# pgAdmin 4, force "The application has lost the database connection:"

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Whenever I put my computer in sleep mode pgAdmin 4 loses the connection to the remote Postgresql database (and that's fine). When I start up the computer again I have two options. Either restart pgAdmin server on my computer or start a query in a pgAdmin window and wait about 10-15 minutes for this prompt:

> **The application has lost the database connection:**
> ⁃ If the connection was idle it may have been forcibly disconnected.
> ⁃ The application server or database server may have been restarted.
> ⁃ The user session may have timed out.
> Do you want to continue and establish a new session?

Is there any way I can force establishing a new session so I can continue my work in the same browser tab without waiting for pgAdmin to timeout and ask me for permission to start a new session?
By the way, is this terrible practice? It is very convenient to just pick-up where I left off but it doesn't seem like a habit that they encourage.

Comment: To be honest this may actually have been an issue with installing Postgresql from apt (which is not updated). Try adding the official repo separately and see if you still have this issue.